# Not sure why I can't resize a div?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why I can't resize a basic div.

i create a div and add the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>New page</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
```

```css
    div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: orange;
    }

    div :hover {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

I looked at example all over the net and this should work but it doesn't. any help is appreciated.

Comment: can give the whole code i can't understand this.Including the div code

Comment: sorry just re-edited.

Comment: did you link the stylesheet ***correctly***

Comment: Can give the whole code with html

Comment: yes the style sheet is linked thats where it gets it's size and color.

Comment: remove the space from `div :hover` so make it `div:hover`

Comment: that's the answer ^

Comment: tried, still no luck.

Comment: you guys rock, man what a simple solution. Thanks to every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in your code. Remove the extra space in `div :hover` as below.

```
div:hover {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div:hover {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it didn't work. so I copied you solution and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between the `div` tag and the `:hover` pseudo-class in your stylesheet:

```css
div:hover { 
... 
}
```